# How to update a list each time in a stateful widget and preserve its state

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a widget where whenever a user clicks an image, the image is sent to my AddListing class.

```
onPressed: ()
{
if(isZoomed == true)
{
Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
AddListing(angle: angle, zoomedVal: zoomLevel, imagePath: widget.picture)));
}
```

So whenever this button is pressed, i navigate to the other UI and pass the
image via imagePath parameter. Now in the other class i.e AddListing where i receive the image i create a list here.

```
final List<String> imagePaths = [];
```

I'm using a PageView.builder for user to swipe through the images that have been clicked. How will I go about adding all the images in the list which are sent by the user when that button is pressed and also keeping the previously taken images as well so that it doesn't create a new list everytime the widget is built.

Comment: use a static variable to store the added images and only init the variable first time! Also, you can use local database or sharedprefs